# How to check if bash input is being redirect to PHP script?

Tags: php, bash, stdin

I'm writing a PHP script and I would like to be able to **optionally** use a file as the script input. This way:

```
$ php script.php < file.txt
```

I'm, actually, able to do that using `file_get_contents`:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

However, if I don't pass a file to the input, the scripts hangs indefinetelly, waiting for an input.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$data = '';
$in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
do {
    $bytes = fread($in, 4096);
    // Maybe the input will be empty here?! But no, it's not :(
    if (empty($bytes)) {
        break;
    }
    $data .= $bytes;
} while (!feof($in));
```

The script waits for `fread` to return a value, but it never returns. I guess it waits for some input the same way `file_get_contents` does.

Another attempt was made by replacing the `do { ... } while` loop by a `while { ... }`, checking for the `EOF` before than trying to read the input. But that also didn't work.

Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions maybe I'm asking too much from PHP client, but there are other **non-PHP** command-line programs that implement this logic – reads the input or ignores/exits.

Comment: yep, you are right. I was on the wrong lane. @Alex Howansky gots it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set STDIN to be non-blocking via the `stream_set_blocking()` function.

```
function stdin()
{
    $stdin = '';
    $fh = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    stream_set_blocking($fh, false);
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        $stdin .= $line;
    }
    return $stdin;
}

$stdin = stdin(); // returns the contents of STDIN or empty string if nothing is ready
```

Obviously, you can change the use of line-at-a-time `fgets()` to hunk-at-a-time `fread()` as per your needs.

Comment: as i understood from the OP , i think it's not about blocking IO , it's about checking the input if isset or not , 'However, if I don't pass a file to the input, the scripts hangs indefinetelly, waiting for an input.'

Comment: Right -- this technique will alleviate that issue. If no input is available on STDIN, this function will immediately return an empty string.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, it worked the way I wanted. I didn't know about `stream_set_blocking` function.